# How to provide AWS credentials from a external REST service

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

We have a vault that rotates AWS secret and access keys and we get them through an API (REST). I would like to retrieve the values through it, and use the refresh function when credentials expire or invalidate.

I have looked all the credentials providers but couldnt find the best one,
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsCredentialsProvider.html

All the documentation in AWS uses hardcoded values, env profiles, local files etc.

We use **Java with Spring boot** and this is what I have tried so far,

```
    public AmazonS3 initS3Client(){
       AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(getAccessKeyFromRestAPI(), getSecretKeyFromRestAPI());
       return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
               .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
               .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
               .build();
   }
```

This is called everytime we need to access AWS, but I feels theres a way to make it a singleton or a bean. So we dont have to create multiple clients or call the REST API multiple times.

Comment: Generally you don't want to be explicit in this way. Instead, just remove with `.withCredentials` and allow the default provider chain to find the authentication method. This is especially useful as deployed services often authenticate in a different way (IAM roles) than you would for local development (IAM users). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html

Comment: @jordanm it’s impossible for the default provider chain to find out the authentication method. As mentioned in the question, the credentials are returned after authenticating a REST API.

Comment: Try to use the `ProcessCredentialsProvider` in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-process.html) provide it a command curl to fetch `credentails` from your rest-api.